# Smallest element in largest row

Tags: java, foreach

I came across this problem in class and I'm stuck on it. I did plenty of research but I'm not being able to fix my code.

I need to create a matrix and find the smallest value in the row of the largest value (I believe this element is called **minimax**). I'm trying to do with a simple 3 x 3 matrix. What I have so far:

```
    Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);       
    int matrizVal[][] = new int[3][3];

    for (int a = 0; a < matrizVal.length; a++)      {
        for (int b = 0; b < matrizVal.length; b++)          {
            System.out.print("(" + a + ", " + b + "): ");
            matrizVal[a][b] = val.nextInt();    
        }
    }

    int largest = matrizVal[0][0];
    int largestrow = 0;
    int arr[] = new int[2];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrizVal.length; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < matrizVal.length; col++){
            if (largest < matrizVal[row][col]){
                largest = matrizVal[row][col];
                largestrow = row;
            }
        }   
    }
```

To find the so called minimax element I decided to create a for each loop and get all the values of largestrow except the largest one.

```
    for (int i : matrizVal[largestrow]){
        if (i != largest){
            System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
```

Here's where I'm stuck! I'd simply like to 'sort' this integer and take the first value and that'd be the minimax. I'm thinking about creating an array of size [matrizVal.length - 1], but not sure if it's gonna work.

I did a lot of research on the subject but nothing seems to help. Any tips are welcome.

(I don't think it is but I apologize if it's a duplicate)

Comment: Given that you now have the 1D array of values (i.e. `matrizVal[largestrow]`), it should be relatively simple to extract the minimum value. Is there a specific runtime complexity you are aiming for?

Comment: Your idea to sort the row containing the maximum value is a good one.  Why not try that?  There are some methods in the [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class you might find helpful.

Comment: What is the expected output if two rows include the same highest value ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you have provided, `matrizVal[largestrow]` should be the row of the matrix that contains the highest valued element.

Given that your task is to extract the smallest value in this array, there are a number of options.

If you want to simply extract the minimum value, a naive approach would go similarly to how you determined the maximum value, just with one less dimension.

For example:

```
int min = matrizVal[largestrow][0];
for (int i = 0; i < matrizVal.length; i++) {
    if (matrizVal[largestrow][i] < min) {
        min = matrizVal[largestrow][i];
    }
}
// min will be the target value
```

Alternatively, if you want to sort the array such that the first element of the array is always the smallest, first ensure that you're making a copy of the array so as to avoid mutating the original matrix. Then feel free to use any sorting algorithm of your choice. `Arrays.sort()` should probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your approach by scanning each row for the maximum and minimum values in that row and then deciding what to do with those values based on the maximum value found in previous rows. Something like this (untested) should work:

```
int largestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int smallestValue = 0; // anything, really

for (int[] row : matrizVal) {
    // First find the largest and smallest value for this row
    int largestRowValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallestRowValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int val : row) {
         smallestRowValue = Math.min(smallestRowValue, val);
         largestRowValue = Math.max(largestRowValue, val);
    }
    // now check whether we found a new highest value 
    if (largestRowValue > largestValue) {
        largestValue = largestRowValue;
        smallestValue = smallestRowValue;
    }
}
```

This doesn't record the row index, since it didn't sound like you needed to find that. If you do, then replace the outer enhanced `for` loop with a loops that uses an explicit index (as with your current code) and record the index as well.

I wouldn't bother with any sorting, since that (1) destroys the order of the original data (or introduces the expense of making a copy) and (2) has higher complexity than a one-time scan through the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a different alternative using Java 8 `Stream` :

```
 int[] maxRow = Arrays.stream(matrizVal).max(getCompertator()).get();
 int minValue = Arrays.stream(maxRow).min().getAsInt();
```

where `getCompertator()` is defined by:

```
private static Comparator<? super int[]> getCompertator() {

    return (a1, a2)->
            Integer.compare(Arrays.stream(a1).max().getAsInt(),
                            Arrays.stream(a2).max().getAsInt()) ;
}
```

Note that it may not give you the (undefined) desired output if two rows include the same highest value .